# Need help getting the difference between a min and max date grouped by patient id using only Python

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, pandas-groupby, date-range

This is a script I am working on for homework for a Big Data class. I got the statistics needed worked out except for this last piece. I need to find the average, min, and max days between a given patient's first appointment and last appointment using only Python. the libraries I have available to me are Numpy, Time, Pandas, and I can import datetime and dateutil in the environment I am working in.

I have gotten as far as getting an output of Patient_id, timestamp amin, timestamp amax using:

```
alvRl = events.groupby(['patient_id']).agg({'timestamp' : [np.min, np.max]})
```

I have tried just simply subtracting the output of timestamp amin from timestamp amax but I get an error. I have also tried relativedelta but it also generates an error. This is what I have so far.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from dateutil import relativedelta as r

'''Given Data'''
events = pd.read_csv('../data/train/events.csv')
mortality = pd.read_csv('../train/mortality_events.csv')

'''Join both dataframes'''
events = events.join(mortality.set_index('patient_id'), on = 'patient_id', rsuffix = '_mortality')

'''use mortality dataframe to list all deceased patients and events dataframe to list all living patients'''
mortality = events.loc[events['label']==1]
events = events.loc[events['label']!=1]

'''changing data type from object to datetime'''
mortality['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(mortality['timestamp'], infer_datetime_format = True)
events['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(events['timestamp'], infer_datetime_format = True)
mortality['timestamp_mortality'] = pd.to_datetime(mortality['timestamp_mortality'], infer_datetime_format = True)
events['timestamp_mortality'] = pd.to_datetime(events['timestamp_mortality'], infer_datetime_format = True)

'''group by patient ids and find minimum and maximum event dates'''
alvRl = events.groupby(['patient_id']).agg({'timestamp' : [np.min, np.max]})
```

If it helps, I am able to get what i need in SQL with the following code, but this homework requires me to do it in Python.

```
SELECT e.patient_id, 
   MIN(e.event_timestamp) as 'min date', 
   MAX(e.event_timestamp)as 'max date', 
   DATEDIFF(day,min(e.event_timestamp),max(e.event_timestamp)) as Delta
FROM Big_Data_Health_HW1.dbo.events e
LEFT JOIN Big_Data_Health_HW1.dbo.mortality_events m on m.patient_id = 
e.patient_id
WHERE m.label is not null
GROUP BY e.patient_id
```

I get a DataFrame object has no attribute 'relativedelta' when using

```
alvRl['RecLen'] = alvRl.relativedelta(alvRl['(timestamp, amin)'],alvRl['(timestamp, amin)'])
```

[Relatice Delta Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F2Qj.jpg)

same error for date_range when I use

```
alvRl['RecLen'] = alvRl.date_range(alvRl['(timestamp, amin'],alvRl['(timestamp, amin'])
```

[Date_Range Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOiRC.jpg)

I get a key error when using:

```
alvRl['RecLen'] = alvRl['(timestamp, amin)'] - alvRl['(timestamp, amin)']
```

[Key Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDcmV.jpg)

I'm just not sure if there is a better way of getting that value.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyWwT.jpg)
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v4sy.jpg)

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I get a DataFrame object has no attribute 'relativedelta'  when using 
    alvRl['RecLen'] = alvRl.relativedelta(alvRl['(timestamp, amin'],alvRl['(timestamp, amin'])

same error for date_range when i use

    alvRl['RecLen'] = alvRl.date_range(alvRl['(timestamp, amin'],alvRl['(timestamp, amin'])

I get a key error when using:

    alvRl['RecLen'] = alvRl['(timestamp, amin)'] - alvRl['(timestamp, amin)']

I'm just not sure if there is a better way of getting that value.

Comment: Which rows raise the error ? can you add the error message in your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract `amin` from `amax` but `alvRl`'s columns are a `MultiIndex`. You have to access them like this:

```
alvRl[('timestamp', 'RecLen')] = (alvRl[('timestamp', 'amax')] - alvRl[('timestamp', 'amin')]) / pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

Or simply drop the first level of the `MultiIndex`:

```
alvRl = alvRl.droplevel(0, axis=1)
alvRl['RecLen'] = (alvRl['amax'] - alvRl['amin']) / pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: this worked you are a mental health life saver. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is because you have renamed `relativedelta` by `r` in this row:

```py
from dateutil import relativedelta as r
```